# How to create an event to handle removal of keyboard on TextView

Tags: android, event-handling, textview

My app has a series of TextView's in a Dialog where the keyboard gets in the way. I'm trying to use the following code to use an event to make the keyboard disappear. It wont compile as it says that 'void is an invalid type for the variable builder'!

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.exindex_dialog, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.ex_index));

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setView(layout);

    builder.setOnItemSelectedListener((OnItemSelectedListener) arg0);
    {
         public void builder.filterStr2.isSelected();  //error is here
         {
             InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
             mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(filterStr2.getWindowToken(), 0);
         }      
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the compiler don't understand what you're trying to do, but neither do I...

What is `arg0` ?

Maybe you're trying to define a `OnItemSelectedListener` listener for your `builder`, but if that's the case, you must implement onItemSelected() and onNothingSelected() methods...

Thus, I don't understand the "isSelected" line...

Maybe, what you trying to do is more something like :

```
builder.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            if (arg3 == filterStr2.id) { // You should maybe change this
                                            // conditional
                InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(filterStr2.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // Do nothing
        }

    });
```